# How can I pass some property from java code to jenkins groovy pipeline

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In one test java file I am reading some values from application I want to send this value to slack through jenkins groovy pipeline.

jenkins groovy file ->

```
node(“master”){
    stage('Backend tests') {

        sh "mvn test -Dfailed_Docs='$failedDocs'"
    }

    stage('Reporting') {
        if (!env.failed_Docs?.isEmpty()){
            slackSend(channel: slackChannel, message: "\n ERROR: below docs are not found: $env.failed_Docs ")
        }
        else{
            slackSend(channel: slackChannel, message: "SUCCESS: hurray no issue!!")
        }
    }
}
```

in java tried to set this value using but not working

```
System.setProperty("failed_Docs","record list after fetching from system")
```

when tried to set this property value using it not getting set.

Comment: what do you mean by not working? did you get an exception? what happened exactly

Comment: Did not get any exception. The property was not getting set. It was showing default value and not the one I set.

Comment: Hi Iam not clearly sure about the issue.. but can you try once mvn test -Dfailed_Docs=\$failedDocs .. Usually in sh for $values we need to put an escape character before $.. like this \$some_variable